# failed to open stream: Permission denied when try to save images

Tags: laravel, image, file, upload

When i try to upload image it show permission denied to the folder where i try to upload the image.

I have checked with dd() and it does contain the file in the $request.
And i have tried solution that i found online but still unable to assess the folder. The solution i have tried is to grant the permission:

```
php artisan cache:clear
icacls "public" /grant Users:F 
composer dump-autoload
```

Here is my code to store the image

```
$image = $request->file('profilePic');
$filename = $request->file('profilePic')->getClientOriginalName();
$image->storeAs('images',$filename);
```

Code in my view.blade.php

```
<div class="form-group row">
    {!! Form::label('client-profilePic', 'Profile Picture', [
        'class' => 'control-label col-sm-3',
        'file' => true
    ]) !!}
    <div class="col-sm-9">
    {!! Form::file('profilePic', null) !!}
    </div>
</div>
```

The result i get now:
fopen(D:\Destop\projectName\public): failed to open stream: Permission denied

Hope you guys can help me figure out how to fix the problem.

Comment: Did you create a folder `images` in your `public` directory? And is the folder writable for the user of your webserver?

Comment: What's the output of `ls -l /path/to/public/folder`?

Comment: I did create the images folder inside public and grant the permission as well. @JulliSchaf

Comment: @Tarasovych 
i am sorry that i cant show you the result? May you tell me what is the code for (by the way i am using Windows)?

Comment: I managed to upload the image by using
`Storage::putFileAs($path,$image,$filename);`
to store. 
Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Code in controller:

images store in public/images directory

```
if($request->profilePic != ''){
     $path = public_path().'/images/';
     $filename = $file->getClientOriginalName();
     $file->move($path, $filename);
}
```

Comment: I managed to upload the image by using
`Storage::putFileAs($path,$image,$filename);`
to store. 
Thank you for your help.